# Why not store files in the database?

Tags: database, heroku, upload, blob

In an app that will be deployed on heroku....

I need to allow users to upload thumbnail images.

A heroku-deployed app of course has no persistent local file storage.

The typical thing to do here, googling around, seems to be storing the files in Amazon S3, or possibly other AWS-hosted cloud storage.

But what if I just stick the images in a postgres blob column?

What are the downsides of doing this?  The upsides are, don't have to pay for other storage, don't have to deal with an additional external system with more opportunities for bugs and outages.  But there must be some good reasons nobody seems to do this, what are they?

Answer (score 7):

A database and S3 are two different storage mechanisms.  How are they different?

**About S3**

Amazon S3 is a highly specialized file storage system.  It minimizes what you can do to basic read/write/delete file operations and optimizes caching for serving data of the entire file stored.

**About Postgres**

Postgres is a SQL relational database with massive flexibility for storing and indexing data for a variety of operations.  You can very well cram binary image data into a row within Postgres.

**Comparing Cost/Scalability**

Why would you choose S3 over Postgres?  Cost and scalability.  Postgres is an expensive, highly skilled generalist.  On Heroku, running a Postgres database could cost you hundreds or thousands of dollars/month based on the amount of data and scale of traffic.

Amazon S3 is an inexpensive and highly scalable solution that perfectly matches your needs (write an image, serve up the image in the context of a web page).

**TL;DR: Amazon S3 is highly optimized for files like images, highly scalable, and relatively inexpensive.**

Comment: Any thoughts on sensitive data that should not be visible public?